# Can't registry slash commands. Getting missing access error

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm getting a missing access error when trying to add slash commands to my guild. I already kicked the bot, deleted the bot and changed the intents.
My intent number is 32265

[image]

This is my code for adding it the commands:

```
const commandFiles = await globPromise(`${process.cwd()}/commands/**/*.js`);
const arrayOfSlashCommands = [];
commandFiles.map((value) => {
     const file = require(value);
     const splitted = value.split("/");
     const directory = splitted[splitted.length - 2];

     if (file.name) {
         const properties = { directory, ...file };
         client.commands.set(file.name, properties);

         arrayOfSlashCommands.push(file);
     }
});

client.on("ready", () => {
     client.guilds.cache.get("783606158669381663").commands.set(arrayOfSlashCommands);
});
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
E:\Development\DiscordBot\Dc_v1_13_FeatureTest\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:298
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Missing Access
    at RequestHandler.execute (E:\Development\DiscordBot\Dc_v1_13_FeatureTest\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:298:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (E:\Development\DiscordBot\Dc_v1_13_FeatureTest\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:50:14)
    at async GuildApplicationCommandManager.set (E:\Development\DiscordBot\Dc_v1_13_FeatureTest\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\ApplicationCommandManager.js:146:18) {
  method: 'put',
  path: '/applications/893555323200237599/guilds/783606158669381663/commands',
  code: 50001,
  httpStatus: 403,
  requestData: {
    json: [
      {
        name: 'search',
        description: 'Search',
        type: undefined,
        options: undefined,
        default_permission: undefined
      }
    ],
    files: []
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you invited the bot in to the server with `applications.commands` scope as well? I believe that is required for it to work
https://imgur.com/nGelDjZ.png

Comment: Thank you, It solved the problem

Comment: Instead of editing the title of your question, mark the answer as correct. That signifies the question is answered, and points users in the way of the correct answer

Answer (score 3):

The solution was to invite the bot using:

[image: these scopes]