# Slash command echo DiscordAPIError: Missing Access in heroku

Tags: javascript, github, heroku, discord.js

```
//slash command to echo 
bot.on("ready", async () => {
    bot.user.setPresence({ activities: [{ name: "Tedi", type: "WATCHING"}] });
    console.log("bye");
    const data = {
        name: "echo",
        description: "Echo your text",
        options: [{
            name: "text",
            type: "STRING",
            description: "The user input",
            required: true,
        }],
    };
const command = await bot.guilds.cache.get('server id number')?.commands.create(data);
})
```

[image: error]

This is the error message I'm getting in heroku and I'm not sure what missing access means.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you enabled `application.commands` in the developer portal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't registry slash commands. Getting missing access error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69410307/cant-registry-slash-commands-getting-missing-access-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very common problem
You can go to the developer department

https://discord.com/developers/applications
Follow the pattern below

[Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0CKZ.jpg)

[Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNBNE.jpg)

Then copy the following URL and paste it on the web page, then choose where you want to create the slash command, and that's it!