# DiscordAPIError: Missing Access when running discord.js bot command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

When I start the bot and use my "ping" command I get this error:

```
    js:350
          throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
                ^
    
    DiscordAPIError: Missing Access
        at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\LiamS\OneDrive\Documenten\Chill Lounge\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350:13)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
        at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\LiamS\OneDrive\Documenten\Chill Lounge\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:51:14)
        at async GuildApplicationCommandManager.set (C:\Users\LiamS\OneDrive\Documenten\Chill Lounge\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\ApplicationCommandManager.js:156:18)
        at async Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\LiamS\OneDrive\Documenten\Chill Lounge\handler\index.js:45:9) {
      method: 'put',
      path: '/applications/996753512807530637/guilds/996381328255750206/commands',
      code: 50001,
      httpStatus: 403,
      requestData: {
        json: [
          {
            name: 'ping',
            name_localizations: undefined,
            description: 'returns websocket ping',
            description_localizations: undefined,
            type: 1,
            options: undefined,
            default_permission: undefined
          }
        ],
        files: []
      }
    }
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't registry slash commands. Getting missing access error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69410307/cant-registry-slash-commands-getting-missing-access-error)

Answer (score -1):

It's a guess, because you didn't post any code, but I'm assuming that you are trying to register "ping" slash command on a specific guild (aka "server"), and the error is likely because your bot is lacking `application.commands` scope on that guild and therefore can't register that command.

So try re-inviting the bot to that guild with `application.commands` scope included and see if it helps.